# Offset OpenGL view?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have two Android OpenGLSurface views next to each other and I'd like to render to a portion of the view offset from the center.

Basically what I want to do is call glViewPort(x,y,width,height) twice with different x for each SurfaceView.

For some reason the glViewPort call gets applied to both surfaceViews though even though I'm using different GL10 instances.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up simply calling glViewPort, then rendering the first view, and then calling glViewPort for the second view, and then rendering the second view.  This fixed the issues.